# Activate user account after register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

After users registration I sent an email to activate the account, but user can log in even the account have not been activated. How can I validate if users account in activated?

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password))) {
  // Success login
} else {
  // Login fail
}
```

Comment: It's not necessarily bad if an unactivated user can log in. You just have to make sure that they don't have the permissions to do something they should not.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1)))
{
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

[Authenticating Users](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users)

In Laravel 5.3 you might want to overwrite `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`'s `credentials` method in your App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController to add `'active' => 1`.

Comment: Can you tell me where to add this in Laravel 5.3?

Comment: Link is broken, here's the L 5.3 link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Answer (score 4):

You must query the database.

If you would have the following db architecture:

```
users
id     name    email    active
--     ----    -----    ------
1      alex    a@a.a    0
```

You might do the following

```
if( ! User::where_email($email)->only('active')) // Adapt the where to your needs
   echo "User not active"
else
   echo "User active"
```

I wrote a Laravel REST API demo service (I use it), which actually has a part where it checks if the user is activated or not: find it here https://github.com/w0rldart/lRapi/blob/master/api/controllers/api/user.php

Comment: I updated the link. Is a new version, with different folder structure. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

Send a link to the users email with a secret key, the key has to be unique, such as a hash of their email address with your application secret key as a salt. Have an endpoint that this link points to which checks that the link is valid using the procedure I mentioned above. If the key you generate matches the one in the email link then you can validate their account and redirect them to the login page.